# How to store on a variable the output from a request?

Tags: node.js

I am having a simple http server that returns a message based on the message returned from another request.

```
const http = require('http');
const app = new http.Server();

var message = 'm1';

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  hostname: '<some-hostname>',
  port: <some_port>
};

app.on('request', (rq, rs) => {
    const m2req = http.request(options, (res) => {
      res.on('data', (d) => {
        message = d;
        process.stdout.write(message);//this prints m2, which is correct
      })
    })

    m2req.on('error', (error) => {
      console.error(error)
    })
    m2req.end();

    rs.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    rs.write(message);// this should print 'm2' but prints 'm1'
    rs.end('\n');

});

app.listen(<some_port>, () => {
});
```

What is the right way so my server prints m2 instead of m1?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try putting all of your `rs.writeHead`, `rs.write`, `rs.end` code inside your `res.on` callback, where you know `m2` is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodejs is asynchronous, you have to use like this below

```
app.on('request', (rq, rs) => {
    const m2req = http.request(options, (res) => {
        var data = []
        res.on("data", (d) => { data.push(d) })
        res.on('end', () => {
            rs.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
            rs.write(Buffer.concat(data).toString());// this should print 'm2' but prints 'm1'
            rs.end('\n');
        })
    })

    m2req.on('error', (error) => {
      console.error(error)
    })
    m2req.end();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are requesting another service, which is an **asynchronous operation**. so the variable `message` is still "m1", because before the service returns the value your `res.write(message)` executes so it's still "m1". You should write `res.send()` `res.write()` `res.writeHead` inside the callback of `res.on`

```
const http = require('http');
const app = new http.Server();

var message = 'm1';

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  hostname: '<some-hostname>',
  port: <some_port>
};

app.on('request', (rq, rs) => {
    const m2req = http.request(options, (res) => {
      res.on('data', (d) => {
        message = d;
        process.stdout.write(message);//this prints m2, which is correct

        rs.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        rs.write(message);// this should print 'm2' but prints 'm1'
        rs.end('\n');
      })
    })

    m2req.on('error', (error) => {
      console.error(error)
    })
    m2req.end();



});

app.listen(<some_port>, () => {
});
```